# FOSElasticBundle share mapping types together

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have two mapping (User and Tasks) and when I search for tasks, I want to able to get found tasks with user information with it.

```
user:
    mappings:
        name: ~
        pic: ~

tasks:
    mappings: 
        content: ~
        created: ~
        user:    integer <-- ID is stored
```

How can I share `types  / model` across each other, so when I pull found task, it should also pull the user info with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't provide a native way to 'join' doc_types. 
Some options:

1. Query for the task and then the user (2 queries)
2. Save the user data inside the tasks doc_type (1 query)

   `tasks:
       mappings: 
           content: ~
           created: ~
           user:
               name:
               pic:`

Comment: which method do you suggest? I'm assuming you will go with the second option since storage is cheap.

Comment: It depends on you exact scenario and what you hope to achieve. For example - will there be changes in the user info? if so and you choose the second option, you'd have to change the data in every task.